# Angular Dialog css styles not applied

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I try to start MatDialog on button press in my application with https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview.

When I start dialog it appears something like this:
[image: Wrong style]

But according the documentation it should look like this:
[image: Valid style]

As you can see in my application it has wrong styles as well as initial button is not highlighting

I use "@angular/material": "^15.2.0" ...

Also I have the following:

```js
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Delete file</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>
    Would you like to delete the following files ?
  </p>
  <div *ngFor="let audioFile of data.audioFileNames">
    {{audioFile}}
  </div>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button id="delete-no" mat-button mat-dialog-close
          (click)="onNoClick()">No</button>
  <button id="delete-yes" mat-button mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial
          (click)="onYesClick()">Yes</button>
</div>
```

Have somebody faced with the same issue ? What have I missed ?

Comment: Have you referenced the angular theme file?

Comment: I have in my project theme.scss, but how to enable it ?

Comment: I use prebuilt theme "styles": ["@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css", "src/styles.scss"]

Comment: can you show your dialog layout?

Comment: Also by some reason for code <div *ngFor="..."> ... </div> I got in browser the following error: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Comment: what about imports? Do you have all necessary modules? CommonModule, MatDialogModule for example

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov Why should I have CommonModule, MatDialogModule in imports ?

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov After your suggestion I add imports CommonModule, MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule and standalone: true and now it works perfectly

Comment: can I post this as an answer?

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov Yes

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov One question to you, how to do the same without standalone: true ?

Comment: Before angular performed standalone components, modules should have been defined in *.module.ts file in imports section. Usually in app.module.ts

Comment: @DenisKotov if you're happy with answer please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out imports section of your app.module or your standalone module in case you are using standalone modules feature. Make sure you have imported CommonModule and especially MatDialogModule.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms but caused by another reason.

I'll leave it here maybe it'll help someone else.

I had something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...]
  declares: [FeatureComponent] // this component makes the call to dialog.open(FooModalComponent)
  exports: [FeatureComponent]
})
class FeatureModule

   
@NgModule({
 imports: [...]
 declares: [FooModalComponent],
 exports: [FooModalComponent]
})
class FooModalModule {}
```

At this point when my dialog displayed it showed without styles.

When I updated the `FeatureModule` to import `FooModalModule`, everything started working.

Hope it helps someone